# Laravel relationships 3-way, ternary relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

Given the following Laravel 10 models.
Users(id,...),
Vehicles (id, primary_user),
UserVehicles (user_id,vehicle_id,vehicle_role_id),
VehicleRoles (id,name)

I am trying to find the correct laravel relationships to associate the following.

- A user can have many vehicles.
- A vehicle can have many users
- A vehicle has only one primary_user
- A user has one role with a vehicle (fleet manager, driver, owner))
- A userVehicle has one role, one vehicle and one user.

**User model**

```
public function vehicles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        Vehicle::class, 
        'user_vehicle', 
        'user_id', 
        'vehicle_id'
    )->withPivot('vehicle_role_id')->as('role');
}
```

**vehicles Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('vehicle_role_id');
}
```

**User vehicle model**

```
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function vehicle(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Vehicle::class,'id','vehicle_id')
        ->whereNull('deleted_at');
}
```

**SQL**

```
select u.name, uv.vehicle_id, vr.name 
from users u 
join user_vehicle uv on uv.user_id = u.id 
join vehicle_roles vr on vr.id = uv.vehicle_role_id
where u.id =1 and vehicle_id = 10
```

[image: ER Diagram]

I just cannot seem to get my head around how to associate the laravel models
I am having issue trying to get the role from the uservehicle relation
Which Model do i define the relationship on and which relationship type

I have tried hasOneThrough, And tried using belongsToMany with pivots and without.

$user = User::find(1);
$vehicles = $user->vehicles;

$vehicles[1]->role->name; //I want to return the role name

**UPDATED my User model above :**
I have been able to get the roleID using the pivot but NOT the **name**

$u = User::find(1); $vs = $u->vehicles; $v = $vs[1]->role;

```
{
  user_id: 1,
  vehicle_id: 10,
  vehicle_role_id: 3,
},
```

Comment: Laravel does not support ternary relationships. In your particular case you can get around it by dropping the `vehicle_role` table (since it's just a single name) and putting the role name in a pivot table that associates users and vehicles so user_vehicle will have a `role` string in it as extra pivot data

Comment: i use the vehiclerole table in other places, not just in that relationship. But what would the pivot table look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User Model`

```
public function vehicles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserVehicle::class, 'user_id');
}
```

`Vehicle Model:`

```
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_vehicles')->withPivot('vehicle_role_id')->withTimestamps();
}

public function primaryUser(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(UserVehicle::class, 'vehicle_id')->where('is_primary', true);
}
```

`VehicleRoles Model:`

```
public function userVehicles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(UserVehicle::class, 'vehicle_role_id');
}
```

`UserVehicle Model:`

```
public function user(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function vehicle(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class, 'vehicle_id');
}

public function role(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(VehicleRoles::class, 'vehicle_role_id');
}
```

you can get the `role name` for a `user's` `vehicle` using

```
$user = User::find(1);
$vehicles = $user->vehicles;

foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    $roleName = $vehicle->pivot->role->name;
    echo "Role name for vehicle " . $vehicle->id . ": " . $roleName . "\n";
}
```

Comment: I am still not able to get the role. my vehicle pivot returns
 $u->vehicles[1]->pivot = {user_id: 1, vehicle_id: 10, vehicle_role_id: 3, };
 $u->vehicles[1]->pivot->role = null;

Comment: Make sure that the VehicleRoles model has a name attribute and that it is correctly filled with the role name for each role in your database. Once you have confirmed this, try running your code again and see if it works as expected.

If you're still having trouble, try using dd($vehicle->pivot) to debug and make sure that the pivot table is returning the correct data. You can also try using `dd($vehicle->pivot->role)` to see if the role relationship is being loaded correctly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this got me 95% there i had to make some other minor change (can't remember what)